# variables from controller to admin/view

Tags: yii

My controller can't return variables to my view/admin.

This is my controller:

```html
public function actionAdmin()
 {
  $model=new Lunch('search');
  $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
  if(isset($_POST['Lunch'])) {
   $model->attributes=$_POST['Lunch'];
   
   // vanaf hier
  $IDdate = $model->date;
  '<pre>';
  var_dump($IDdate);
  '</pre>';
  $this->redirect(array('Lunch/admin', 'id'=>$model->date));
 
 //tot hier
  }
  $this->render('admin',array(
  'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }
```

This is my admin:

```html
<?php
   $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'date',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>


<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'date',
        CHtml::listData(Lunch::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'date'));?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save', array("id"=>"submitLunch")); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

What do I wrong :(.
if I gave you guys less info just say!

Comment: Can you specify the error?

Comment: Where are you using `$id` in your view?

Comment: We need the error to understand what is going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the CController's redirect method tries to redirect the user, then **terminates the application** by default (see the second parameter of the method, which is true by default).

```
redirect(mixed $url, boolean $terminate=true, integer $statusCode=302)
```

This uses also the HTTP headers for redirection, which means you can not print anything before this method. If you print/echo anything, it also sends the request header to the client, so the **redirection will fail**, because the headers are already sent.

You have to delete this part:

```
    '<pre>';
    var_dump($IDdate);
    '</pre>';
```

and it should work fine.

If that still does not solve your problem, then please check the `Lunch` model's **validation rules**. You have to set at least one rule for the `date` attribute for the `$model->attributes = $_POST['Lunch'];` to take effect *(it won't assign 'unsafe' attributes without any rule)*

So put this `rules` function in your `Lunch` model:

```
class Lunch extends CActiveRecord {
...

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('date','length','max'=>255)
        );
    }

...
}
```

You can read more about model validation rules here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/
Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you use "ajax" in your form, you get an array with 'ajax' value.

So, you can try this:

```html
public function actionAdmin(){

 $model=new Lunch('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
 $model->attributes=$_POST['Lunch'];
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'date-form') {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    //non-ajax code
 $this->render('admin',array(
 'model'=>$model,
 ));     
}
```